# Подскажите с JS добавление классов к родительским элементам

Tags: javascript

Вот есть у меня такая наработка кода, всё работает, но мне нужно чтобы я добавил класс не к **span** тегу, а к строкам **tr** в которых был найден данный текст.

Вот как бы так сделать, чтобы добавить класс к **tr.part** содержащие символы "**-08-**" в **span** тегах?

У меня есть одна идея, как это можно реальзовать через кучу условий "**if**", сделать что-то вроде такой же проверки на символы "**-08-**" в строке "**tr**", но так как в строке предпологается не одна ячейка "**td**", которые так же могут содержать эти символы, а так же возможен различный объем текста в другх ячейках **td** тогда уже не получится так просто применить метод **slice**...

Вот поэтому возможно как-то из этого кода, что я прилагаю можно сделать проверку **tr.part** на наличие в теге **span.span-style** символов  "**-08-**", и если они там найдены, нужно добавить класс "**hide**" строкам **tr.part**; и ещё причина по которой я задаю позицию этих символ, это потому что они являются как бы целой строкой, вот пример записи в теге **span.span-style** : "**2021-08-15**".

```
let selectorPart = document.querySelectorAll('tr.part');
console.log(selectorPart);
let selectorAll = document.querySelectorAll('tr.part>td>span.span-style'); // выбрали все селекторы тега span класса "span-style"
console.log(selectorAll);
let myArray = Array.from(selectorAll);
console.log(myArray);
// Через фильтр задаём позицию и находим строки содержащие "-08-"
let filterAug = myArray.filter(function (item, index, array) {
    return item.innerText.slice(4, 8) == "-08-";
});
// Перебераем найденные элементы массива и с помощью функции даём класс каждому элементу
filterAug.forEach(hide);
function hide(item) {
item.classList.add('hide');
console.log(item);


<!-- Пример HTML разметки --!>
    <table>
    <tr class="part">
     <td> Словак, 15 т </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-08-14</span> 
     Зол. №15
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-09-06</span> 
     Зол. №12
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-09-14</span> 
     Зол. №21
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-09-20</span> 
     Зол. №33
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="part">
     <td> Ловаш, 5 т </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-07-14</span> 
      Зол. №15
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-08-06</span> 
     Зол. №12
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-09-14</span> 
     Зол. №21
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-09-20</span> 
     Зол. №33
     </td>
    </tr>
   <tr class="part">
     <td> Ловаш, 5 т </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-07-14</span> 
      Зол. №15
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-09-06</span> 
     Зол. №12
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-09-14</span> 
     Зол. №21
     </td>
     <td><span class="span-style">2021-09-20</span> 
     Зол. №33
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Как насчёт небольшого примера HTML-разметки?

Comment: добавил.) на три строки, но строк предпологается гораздо больше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr')

tr.forEach(el=>{
  let str = el.innerHTML
  el.closest('tr').classList.remove('hide');
  if (/-08-/i.test(str)) el.closest('tr').classList.add('hide')
})
```

В виде функции:

```
function hideRow(text){
    let tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

  tr.forEach(el=>{
    el.closest('tr').classList.remove('hide');
    const str = el.innerHTML;
    const reg = new RegExp(text, 'i');
    if (reg.test(str)) el.closest('tr').classList.add('hide');
  })
}

hideRow('-08-');
```

Comment: Ух ты - так просто.) Спасибо.)

Comment: @ЕвгенийJS: ответ дали бы ещё быстрее, если сразу давать в вопросе необходимые вводные ;-)

Comment: @UModeL хм, а как можно сделать, чтобы наоборот в строках где не найдено, символов "-08-" добавился класс?

Comment: @ЕвгенийJS: `if (!/-08-/i.test(str)) el.closest('tr').classList.add('hide')`

Comment: @UModeL спасибо.) Просто подобный синтаксис написания мне незнаком. Пока только основы-основ изучил.) Чтобы хотя бы уметь читать код.)

Comment: @UModeL Здраствуйте, а можете ещё подсказать как сделать проверку через сравнение с переменной? Т.е. в условии для поиска мы задаём определенные символы "-08-" , а как вместо этого подставить туда переменную? Которая к примеру будет равна тем же символам "-08-"?

Comment: К примеру есть ещё один тег  <button class="visableAug">08</button> в JS let visableAugS = document.querySelector('.visableAug'); получаю содержимое этого тега, вот дальше как-то нужно это вставить в условие сравнения, вместо текста "-08".

Comment: @Евгений JS обновил ответ. Берете нужный вам текст для поиска и вызываете функцию, передавая аргументом ваш текст.

Comment: @PavelNazarian такс, всё разобрался.)) Подставил то что нужно всё заработало, СПАСИБО! :)